# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'predicted' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

i try to search about this problem but i couldn't find,that i try to apply ggplot for the relation between the two variables (predictor and predicted x,y), the method was linear regression model (lm) but i got this error

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'predicted' not found

and this my code:

```
# Install tidymodels if you haven't done so
install.packages("rlang")
install.packages("tidymodels")
install.packages("dplyr")
# Library for modeling
library(tidymodels)

# Load tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

library(dplyr)
URL <- 'https://dax-cdn.cdn.appdomain.cloud/dax-noaa-weather-data-jfk-airport/1.1.4/noaa-weather-sample-data.tar.gz'
download.file (URL, destfile='noaa-weather-sample-data.tar.gz')
untar('noaa-weather-sample-data.tar.gz',tar = 'internal')
dataset<- read.csv ('noaa-weather-sample-data/jfk_weather_sample.csv')
head(dataset)
glimpse(dataset)
subset_data <- data.frame(dataset$HOURLYRelativeHumidity,dataset$HOURLYDRYBULBTEMPF,dataset$HOURLYStationPressure,dataset$HOURLYWindSpeed,dataset$HOURLYPrecip)
subset_data<-setNames(subset_data,c('HOURLYRelativeHumidity','HOURLYDRYBULBTEMPF','HOURLYStationPressure','HOURLYWindSpeed', 'HOURLYPrecip'))

head(subset_data,10)

unique(subset_data$HOURLYPrecip)


subset_data <- subset_data %>%mutate(HOURLYPrecip = replace(HOURLYPrecip, HOURLYPrecip == "T", "0.0"))
View(subset_data)

install.packages('stringr ')
library(stringr)
subset_data$HOURLYPrecip <-  str_remove(subset_data$HOURLYPrecip, pattern = 's') 

unique(subset_data$HOURLYPrecip)
subset_data$HOURLYPrecip <- as.numeric(subset_data$HOURLYPrecip)
subset_data$HOURLYRelativeHumidity <- as.numeric(subset_data$HOURLYRelativeHumidity)
subset_data$HOURLYDRYBULBTEMPF <- as.numeric(subset_data$HOURLYDRYBULBTEMPF)
subset_data$HOURLYWindSpeed <- as.numeric(subset_data$HOURLYWindSpeed)


     str(subset_data1)
        subset_data1 <- setNames(subset_data,c('relative_humidity','dry_bulb_temp_f','station_pressure','wind_speed', 'precip'))
        
        #library(rsample)
        set.seed(1234)
        #split_data <- initial_split(subset_data1)
        dt<- sort(sample(nrow(subset_data1), nrow(subset_data1)*.8))
        train_data<- subset_data1 [dt,]
        test_data <- subset_data1 [-dt,]
        
        install.packages('ggplot')
        library(ggplot2)
        hist(train_data$relative_humidity)
        hist(train_data$dry_bulb_temp_f)
        hist(train_data$station_pressure)
        hist(train_data$wind_speed)
        hist(train_data$precip)
        
        install.packages('stats')
        library(stats)
        linear_reg1 <- lm (precip ~ relative_humidity, train_data)
        linear_reg2 <- lm (precip ~ dry_bulb_temp_f, train_data)
        linear_reg3 <- lm (precip ~ wind_speed, train_data)
        linear_reg4 <- lm (precip ~ station_pressure, train_data)
        
        
        #ggplot(train_data, aes(x = train_data$relative_humidity ,y= train_data$precip)) + geom_point()+ stat_smooth(method = 'lm', col ='red')
        ggplot(train_data, aes(x= relative_humidity, y= precip))+
          geom_smooth(method='lm',se=FALSE ,color='red')+ 
          geom_segment(aes(xend= relative_humidity ,yend = predicted),alpha=.2)+
          geom_point()+
          geom_point(aes(y = predicted),shape=1)+
          theme_bw()
```

Comment: I think you might have a misconception about the workings of ggplot2. One layer, i.e. `geom_point(aes(y = predicted), ...)` is blind to what happens in other layers, i.e. `geom_smooth(...)`. If you want to to use some prediction from a model in a layer, it is highly recommended to do that outside of ggplot2.

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't have a column called `predicted` in your data set. Presumably you want this to be the predicted value of precipitation based on humidity. In that case, you can easily create the column in your data frame using your first linear model:

```r
train_data$predicted <- predict(linear_reg1, train_data)

ggplot(train_data, aes(x = relative_humidity, y = precip)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = relative_humidity, yend = predicted), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', se = FALSE , color = 'red') + 
  geom_point(aes(y = predicted), shape = 1, alpha = 0.1) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

As you can see, a linear model is no good here. It predicts negative precipitation at low humidity and underestimates the precipitation at high humidity.